# The Complement Cat

Tags: string, restricted-source, printable-ascii, answer-chaining

**Objective** Write a full program that outputs (to STDOUT or closest alternative) an arbitrary string of text, no more than 64 characters long. Simple enough, right? Well, here's the catch: You may not use any characters that were present in the previous answer's output. That's right, *none* of them.

Thus, you are trying to be the last answer for a total of three days. That is, you want no one to answer the question in the 72 hours following the posting of your question.

### Some rules

- Your answer (and output) may only contain printable ASCII characters, newlines (carriage returns included), and tabs.
- Your answer's output may not be the same as another answer's output. Two output's are the same if and only if they use the exact same characters.
- You may use any language that was not specifically made for this challenge, even if it was made after the challenge. (This language, of course, must be testable.)
- You may not use any language that was previously used.
- Your entry may not include comments. You may, of course, provide an extra commented program.
- You *may not* answer twice in a row.
- Your program must be at least 1 byte.

### Entry format

Your answer should look generally like the following:

```
# {Language}
Uses: `characters present in the output`

Does not use: `characters used in the previous output` from [previous submission, language](link-to-previous-submission]

    {program}

Outputs:

    {output}
```

An explanation with your answer is appreciated.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ And empty outputs?

Comment: @jimmy23013 It isn't advised, but yeah, they're allowed.

Comment: As [exiting with an error is usually allowed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/25180), this makes it impossible to win unless we run out of interpreted languages.

Comment: I'm wildly confused about what is being asked. I have to print any <=64 char string, and I can't use the characters in the latest submission's output?

Comment: (Also, a leaderboard that keeps track of used languages alphabetically would be cool.)

Comment: @Mauris Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ah, okay; the bit about "character space" is really confusing IMO. That term doesn't mean anything... Maybe you should rewrite it?

Comment: @Mauris I define it.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ, character space == "The exact same characters as the last submission, in any order"?

Comment: @StewieGriffin The exact same characters as _any previous submission_ in any order.

Comment: "You may not use any characters that were present in the previous answer's output." Do you mean you can't use them in the source code, or they can't appear in the output? You tagged this [tag:restricted-source], so I'm guessing the former...

Comment: The former @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: Could you add a snippet to generate a list of the languages that have been used?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Yeah, working on it

Comment: This is really confusing - aside from the issue of "character space" mentioned above, why would this challenge, as stated, make you want to be the *last* person to answer (for any period of time)?

Comment: @question_asker If nobody can come up with an answer to follow yours, you win the challenge (and get the green checkmark). For example, if I wrote a program that outputs every printable ASCII character, it would be impossible to follow (ignoring [those annoying languages](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55425/31388) that generate output for the empty program).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yeah, the idea of "winning" occurred to me after it was too late to make an edit. That said, I'm still confused as to whether it's the code, output, or both that is not to be duplicated, and whether it's *all previous entries* or just *the* previous entry.

Comment: @question_asker Your code cannot contain any of the characters from the *previous* answer's output; your output cannot use the same set of characters as *any* previous output. If the code for the first answer is `foo` and it outputs `bar`, the code for the next answer cannot contain `b`, `a`, or `r`; no subsequent answer can output `abr`, `arb`, `bar`, `bra`, `rab`, or `rba`. (Yes, I agree this was very confusing.)

Comment: I think it's been 72 hours since my entry.

Comment: @Mauris and so it has! Congratulations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ruby

```
$><<'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" '
```

Does not use `` abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}\~_^[]|` `` from the [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67414/3852).

Prints, and hence uses, `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"`, a space, and a newline.

Answer (score 5):

## Brainfuck

Uses: `-.`

Does not use: `` !"%&')+,0123456789<=>ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPRSTWXYZ]`acefghjlnoprstux{| `` [from CJam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67296/45447).
Thanks to SuperJedi

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.---------------------------.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
```

Outputs:

```
; (){}[]"'
```

Comment: This could be altered to only use `-` and `.`. That's my proposal for the purposes of the challenge.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/obzsvot

Comment: Sorry, I took the `uses` portion to mean that those were the entities used in the code. Gimme a goddamn minute before you start using downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth

Uses: `` ()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefg ``.

Doesn't use: `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@[\]^_`abcdefghijklnsm{|}~ `` from [previous submission in Octave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67304/3852).

Code:

```
pMCMryyTyyytytttT
```

Output:

```
()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefg
```

Comment: Is there a space in there? I guess there aren't any tabs or newlines that aren't shown? It looks like the next answer must be a whitespace answer (or at least close)...

Comment: No whitespace in the output that's mine; I don't know if the language appends a newline though

Answer (score 3):

## CJam

Uses: `0123456789:;_bc`

Does not use:  `!GSaefgimnoprstuw`, from [previous submission, MATLAB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67293/25180)

```
183185535513294435547695067785526290427932963043839368372854060721693597139131275368051870173845056551161192991350318233082749156998652_;128b:c
```

Outputs:

```
 !"%&')+,0123456789<=>ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPRSTWXYZ]`acefghjlnoprstux{|
```

Comment: Well, I can't beat this.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave

Uses:  ``` !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@[\]^_``abcdefghijklnsm{|}~ ``` and a newline in the output.

Doesn't use: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"` from [previous submission in Microscript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67299/31516).

Code:

```
[' ':'@','[':'`','{':'~',('@'+' '):('>'+'/')]
```

Output:

```
ans =
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`abcdefghijklm
```

Explanation:

This is a collection of consecutive ASCII-characters. The code is equivalent to:

```
[char(32:64) char(91:96) char(123:126) char(96:109)]
```

Where `char(32:64)` are the ASCII characters from 32 to 64 (space to @). In order to get the alphabet-part in the end of the output, I had to add characters, as I couldn't use `a` and `m`. `@+`  equals 96 (``) and `>+/` equals 109 (m)

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ, explanation included =)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl

Uses:  `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}` (with space)

Does not use: `` "#$%'()*+,-./123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`{|~ `` from [previous submission in Unreadable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67380/30164)

```perl
eval q!print uc q&} abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&!and eval q}print q&0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&}and eval q&print length for qw!a bc def ghij klmno pqrstu vwxyzab cdefghij klmnopqrs!&
```

Outputs:

```
} ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789
```

---

…the old joke about monkeys writing code comes to mind…

[You can run the program online.](https://ideone.com/fTr98T)

This program abuses the weird features of Perl to write code in just about any subset of ASCII:

- Functions can be called without parentheses in some cases (unsure about exact rules)
- `q#text#` where `#` can be almost any character is the same as `"text"`
- `qw#word1 word2 word3#` like the above is the same as `["word1", "word2", "word3"]`
- `for` loops and other things can be appended to lines, eliminating any punctuation

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6

Previous answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67406/39022

Source does not contain `!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, space, or newline.

```
alert`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}\\~_^[]|\``
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}\~_^[]|`
```

(Lowercase alphabet, curly brackets, backslash, tilde, underscore, carat, square brackets, pipe, and backtick)

Comment: I believe you mean *back*slash instead of *forward* slash. But nice entry!

Comment: @ETHproductions You're right about the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3

Uses: `!CGaceilmnoprstw z`.

```
print("Germanic Capitalization is awesome!")
```

Simply prints `Germanic Capitalization is awesome!` with no restrictions. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB

Uses:  `!GSaefgimnoprstuw` and newline.

Does not use: `!CGaceilmnoprstw z` from [previous submission, Python 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67287/31516).

```
[83,116,101,119,105,101,32,71,114,105,102,102,105,110,32,105,115,32,97,32,112,114,111,109,105,110,101,110,116,32,103,101,110,105,111,117,115,33,'']
```

Prints:

```
ans =

Stewie Griffin is a prominent genious!
```

Answer (score 2):

## Microscript II

Previous answer: [here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67286/the-complement-cat/67298#67298) Program does not use semicolon, space, parentheses, curly brackets, square brackets, single straight quotes, or double straight quotes. This program would be a lot shorter if it didn't have to avoid quotes.

Output includes: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"`, and a newline.

Program:

```
97Kp98Kp99Kp100Kp101Kp102Kp103Kp104Kp105Kp106Kp107Kp108Kp109Kp110Kp111Kp112Kp113Kp114Kp115Kp116Kp117Kp118Kp119Kp120Kp121Kp122Kp""P65Kp66Kp67Kp68Kp69Kp70Kp71Kp72Kp73Kp74Kp75Kp76Kp77Kp78Kp79Kp80Kp81Kp82Kp83Kp84Kp85Kp86Kp87Kp88Kp89Kp90Kp123456789qh
```

Exact output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"123456789"
```

Comment: And the `Does not incude` bit.

Answer (score 2):

## Unreadable

Uses: `` "#$%'()*+,-./123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`{|~ ``

Does not use: `` ()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefg `` from [previous submission in Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67313/46855)

> '"'""'""'"'""'"'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'"'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""

Outputs:

```
"#$%'()*+,-./123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`{|~
```

---

In case you are wondering, yes, programming by hand in this language is painful, so I made this script (in JavaScript) to generate the code:

```js
var program = `"`,
    output = "\"#$%'()*+,-./123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`{|~";
for(var i = 1, c = 0; c < output.length; i++) {
  program = `'""` + program;
  if(i == output.charCodeAt(c)) {
    program = `'"` + program;
    c++;
  }
}
program;
```

I used the Python interpreter for Unreadable [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Marinus/Unreadable_Interpreter) to run the code.

Comment: Having a space in there would make life hard for the next one =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin That's true. Is it too late to edit? xD TBH though, I think this challenge can go on for a lot longer because there's many languages which have pre-set variables in either upper or lower-case letters, so just the one character would be a valid answer. (Even though it wouldn't be too interesting and makes it very easy for the next answer!)

Comment: I think it's too late now. Someone _might_ be working on a solution in for instance whitespace, and suddenly adding a space in the output will probably make them annoyed.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yeah, that was my reasoning too.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript

Uses: space, newline, `!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`.

Doesn't use `0-9A-Za-z{` or space from [previous submission in Perl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67394/3852).

The code:

```
'!'.!=('['.!=,>''+
```

The output:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

And a trailing newline.

[Try it here.](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=JyEnLiE9KCdbJy4hPSw-Jycr&input=)